# Angular 6: How to make a set of service calls in parallel and process Data once all of them are completed

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular6, rxjs6

I am working on Angular 6+ web-app using rxjs 6+ .

There is a set of services(all are different and make different http calls) .
Basically these services are used to initialize the app.

My requirement is to call these services in parallel and wait untill all of them are finished . Once finished , I need to process the responses received . 
I have studied a lot on this and found that forkJoin and combineLatest can be my friend. 
And i have implemented the same in the following way  :

```
 getInitialData() {

 this._authService.openCorsConnection().subscribe(res => { 
  forkJoin(
    this._authService.x(),
    this._tService.getSystemDate(),
    this._tService.getTemp(),
    this._tService.getSettings()
  ).pipe(
    catchError( err => {
      console.log('gor error',err);
      if (err.status == 401) {
          // this._router.navigateByUrl('/unauthorize');
          return EMPTY;
      } else {
          return throwError(err);
      }
 }),
    map(([x,y,z,p])=>{
           console.log('sucesss',{x,y,z,p});          
            return {x,y,z,p}
    }),
  finalize(()=>{
        console.log('Executing Finally');
        processData();

  })
  );
});
 }
```

But These are not executing . Here are the services :

```
x(): Observable<any> {          
const xUrl  = EnvironmentConfiguration.endPointConfig.xServiceEndpoint;
          let serviceMethod: String = 'x';
          let requestObj: any = this._utilHelperSvc.getRequestObject(xUrl  , { "y": "" }, serviceMethod);
          return this._http.post<any>(requestObj.url,{ "pid": "" } , requestObj)
          .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError('x', {}))
          );
      }
```

Do i need to modify services ? 
I am not able to figure out how to solve this.

Can anybody please Suggest some better solution or different approach for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you try replacing forkJoin with combineLatest? Did that work?

Comment: @YGLin yes.. both are behaving in the same way. Even if a write subscribe on services, the forkJoin's callbacks are not executing...

Comment: I noticed that you have 2-level of subscribe, are you sure the first one, openCorsConnection(), emit as expected? 
If so, maybe you need to check those service calls one by one to make sure each emit successfully.
Can't help you much further, sorry~

Comment: If `forkJoin` doesn't emit any value then one of you source Observables doesn't emit anything or doesn't complete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Use [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html) or [forkjoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html).

Demos :

- [Demo with forkJoin](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dfsaqt?file=index.ts)
- [Demo with zip](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-b7kgk2?file=index.ts)

**Explanation**

You don't need to wait for `forkJoin` to process the responses, it works the other way around. Instead, *prepare* all the jobs that need to be done, and simply wait for completion.

Here is what I mean:

```
let process1$ = timer(1000);
let process2$ = timer(2000);
let process3$ = timer(3000);

const doSthg1 = pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('Process 1 has finished')),
  map(() => 'Process 1 has finished')
)

const doSthg2 = pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('Process 2 has finished')),
  map(() => 'Process 2 has finished')
)

const doSthg3 = pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('Process 3 has finished')),
  map(() => 'Process 3 has finished')
)

forkJoin(doSthg1(process1$), doSthg2(process2$), doSthg3(process3$)).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('Now I am complete');
});
```

[Demo with forkJoin](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dfsaqt?file=index.ts)

This works as long as your processes are not chained, i.e the input of one does not depend on the output of another.

**why isn't my code working ?**

Because you don't actually subscribe to `forkJoin`.
Solution : for example, you can use `concatMap` to transform `this._authService.openCorsConnection()` into another Observable :

```
getInitialData(){
  this._authService.openCorsConnection().pipe(
    concatMap(() => forkJoin(this._authService.x(),
      this._tService.getSystemDate(),
      this._tService.getTemp(),
      this._tService.getSettings()
    )),
    catchError(err => {
      console.log('gor error', err);
      if (err.status == 401) {
        return EMPTY;
      } else {
        return throwError(err);
      }
    }),
  ).subscribe(() => processData());
}
```

**zip**

You could use `zip` instead of `forkJoin` if:

1. all processes emit only once, then complete : for example http Get or Post requests.
2. you want to get join outputs from your sources.

implementation:

```
zip(doSthg1(process1$), doSthg2(process2$), doSthg3(process3$))
.subscribe(
      ([x,y,z]) => {
      console.log(`x=${x}, y=${y}, z=${z}`);
});
```

[Demo with zip](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-b7kgk2?file=index.ts)

Comment: @madjaous Thanks.. i will try this... Also i have updated the service body in my question. can you pls tell if any modification is required ?

Comment: yes i need to process data for each service . I am not sure  "do all your services emit once" means but yes.. all service returns data for sure.

Comment: Thanks buddy.. Will let you know once i implement.

Answer (score 0):

I have just do few days ago after lot's of search.

The main thing is how you call list of API.

If you call API from **component.ts** then you got data in that. The twist is when you call API by service the you have to store the **reference** of API call.

I have done this by this way...

```
var pendingAPIList : any = [];
```

you can add API list in array with ref of observable.

```
return new Observable(observer => {
    var obj = {
       url:url,
       param:param,
       ref : observer  // <-- Hear is the main trick 
    }
    this.pendingAPIList.push(obj);  // Add multiple API in array
})
```

When all API added then call then...

```
Observable.forkJoin(this.pendingAPIList).subscribe(response){

     // You will get data in array 
     // Now return all API res in their subscribers at .ts file... 

     for(let i = 0 ; i < this.pendingAPIList.lengh ; i++  ){
        this.pendingAPIList[i].ref.next(response[i]);
        this.pendingAPIList[i].ref.complete();   
     }
}
```

**This is working fine for me... :)**

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Promise.all, in the next example I call an API with many times in parallel with different parameters. In the end when all finished I fill the list so the binding jumps in:

```
let [invLogs, custLogs, contactLogs, oppLogs, errLogs, genLogs, pLogs, costLogs] = await Promise.all([this.logService.getLogsByTypeAsync(2, this.nr, 0), this.logService.getLogsByTypeAsync(7, this.nr, 0),
  this.logService.getLogsByTypeAsync(8, this.nr, 0), this.logService.getLogsByTypeAsync(9, this.nr, 0), this.logService.getLogsByTypeAsync(11, this.nr, 0), this.logService.getLogsByTypeAsync(12, this.nr, 0),this.logService.getLogsByTypeAsync(0, this.nr, 0),this.logService.getLogsByTypeAsync(1, this.nr, 0)]);
  this.latestInvLogs = invLogs;
  this.latestContactLogs = contactLogs;
  this.latestCustLogs = custLogs;
  this.latestErrorLogs = errLogs;
  this.latestOppLogs = oppLogs;
  this.latestGeneralLogs = genLogs;
  this.latestProjectLogs = pLogs;
  this.latestCostLogs = costLogs;
```

Comment: It will not work with observables.

Comment: No, change it to a Promise:  Promise<entity[]> instead of Observable<entity[]>. And await the result: return await lastValueFrom(response);